# Why are some Windows registry values readable by VBScript but not VBA?

Tags: vba, windows, vbscript, registry

I'm trying to read a registry value using VBScript and VBA.

This works in VBScript but in VBA it returns the read error below:

```
Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ID = objshell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductID")
```

[image]

And I noted that I can't actually see the value in the regedit app with/without running as administrator. Is this something to do with registry virtualisation?

UPDATED BASED ON REGISTRY REDIRECTION COMMENTS

Since the code above runs on 64 bit Office, it should be possible to craft something like this, but the 32 bit part still throws an error.

```
#If Win64 Then ' 64 bit Office
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductID")
#Else          ' 32 bit Office
    Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductID")
#End If
```

Comment: What kind of 'read error'. It should not be working only if the user running VBA code does not have permissions to writhe to the Registry. The above code works for me (in VBA). I used a shorter code line: `Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductID")` and it returns correctly.

Comment: Added the error screenshot @FaneDuru I have admin rights but I don't understand why running as a script in WScript works but VBA doesn't.

Comment: Doesn’t that error also mean it might not exist where it’s trying to read, what is VBA running in and is it 32/64 bit? Chances are your VBScript is looking in the 64 bit reg while VBA is reading the 32 bit one.

Comment: [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector). Presumably, your VBA code is running from a 32-bit installation of Office, whereas the VBScript is executing from the 64-bit scripting host.

Comment: That looks like it could be it @user692942 and iinspectable having run the same code on Office 64 bit with success. Happy to mark that as the answer. I updated the question to add Office bitness conditional statements. Any ideas how to make the 32 bit part work?

Comment: @JamieGarroch-MVP you could run VBScript from the 32-bit subsystem? Something like `%systemroot%\SysWOW64\wscript.exe scriptfile.vbs` or `cscript.exe` respectively depending on how you launch your vbs file.